# Asp.Net MVC 5 Client Validation without Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following inputs in my mvc view

```
 <input class="input-group-field" id="name" name="name" type="text" size="1" required="">
 <input class="input-group-field" id="email" name="email" type="email" size="1" required="">
```

My MVC View is working with ajax requests only, there is no model binding.

My Ajax request gets fired on a buttons click event.

I know that without a form tag, the html 5 validation is not working.

I have tried to setup a form around the inputs and prevent the form from getting submitted.

```
    $('#valForm').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

The button:

```
<button class="button green post" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

But the click event from the button is still fired.

```
  $('.button.post').on('click', function () {
    //fires
  });
```

If I change the buttons listener from click to submit, nothing happens.

```
  $('.button.post').on('submit', function () {
    // does not fire fire
  });
```

Any I Idea how I can trigger the clientside html5 validation without actually submitting a form?

Thanks

Comment: add the button listener

Comment: actually the button event is not needed now since the type of your button is `submit` it will automatically submit the form without attaching event of your button. And submit event for the button is not working because submit only works for `forms`

Comment: So I should put my ajax request in the form submit handler? How can I prevent the actions if the form is not valid?

Comment: So the twist here is this, since you already prevented the default behavior of submit, you need to implement it by yourself (using ajax or any handler that can send request to the web server). Yes put your ajax there add condition if form is not valid dont trigger the ajax. Html5 validation works first before the submit event is triggered so no need to worry about it :)

Comment: Thanks katana. So the HTML5 validation will be triggered, messages displayed like "This field is required", but I need to check myself again if the field have values before firing the ajax request, right?

Comment: Yes you are on the right track sir :) Or you can add more html5 validation so you will not revalidate again in javascipt

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in several different ways. I don't know how you defined your form/form-tag but since you posted your button i can see why your click event is not caught. Your selector is wrong.

This selector

```
$('.button.post')
```

matches anthing with class button and class post. Your button does not have class button though, so you should change the selector to

```
$('button.post')
```

instead.

UPDATE: I reread your post. It seems like your button handler is already fired, meaning you probably made a typo when posting your question here. You also want to trigger html5 validation without sumitting the page.

You should end up with something like this:

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I did not copy the actual button, there is a button class

Comment: Yeah ok - try my modified submit handler - notice the selector is 'form' which will catch any form submit...